# Solution for migrating to minor sites

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, migration

Often I want to migrate a question to codereview, or programmers, or cs.  However, we are only provided a very finite list for where to close as belonging on a different site (superuser, tex, etc.).  The reason usually given for not giving us 
options for those more minor sites is that the person making the suggestion often doesn't realize that the question doesn't actually belong on the other site either.

Like:

> What is a better server-side programming language, Java or PHP?

With a close-voter thinking:

> Oh, that belongs on programmers, I want to migrate it there.

Of course, the question doesn't belong on either site (or any SE site, for that matter) and so the system tries to minimize these sorts of incorrect migrations by not even allowing close-voters to suggest it short of a custom moderation flag.

I think the limitation makes sense, so far as it goes -- we don't want five random close voters to unwelcomely move this question to a site that will reject it.  However, the lack of such an option provides an irritating bump in the usual close process. Since we, as close-voters, can't vote to close as belonging on the site where we think it belongs, we are often inclined to suggest that they ask the question on codereview, for example.  (In addition, of course, to voting to close for whatever reason most makes sense on SO)  However, if they *do* end up asking the question on the site we recommend, the OP has now created a dup if a moderator were to ever migrate the question over.  However, if we don't make such a suggestion -- and it doesn't get migrated -- the user may have no notion that the other site exists at all.  (And I think formulating a comment that addresses all these concerns is clunky at best)

I wonder if there is room here for a new queue for each stack exchange network.  For sites that are not already on the default list of sites to which questions can migrate, maybe we could *still* apply a close vote for where we think the question ought to belong.  The *receiving* site could then review a new queue that shows them lists of questions coming from other sites that have votes to migrate questions to theirs.  If they vote to accept it, then if the original SO question is ultimately closed, it will be migrated to the site that accepted it (assuming there is no ambiguity between different sites that have been suggested).  Or, if the majority voted to migrate to a site that rejects it, it could simply be closed as being off-topic in a general sense.

Among the benefits of this approach:

- Close-voters who *think* it ought to belong on another site have a chance to communicate this notion in a way that doesn't result in a cross-post.
- Sites where the question truly does belong will benefit from an increase in presumably high-quality questions (since they're playing gatekeeper and moderators can't get to as much as close-voters).
- The OP of the question will have a better chance of getting his question answered, and less likely to feel frustrated because their question was closed on the site to which they asked it.

Comment: Related on MSE: [How to discourage people encouraging reposting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195008/how-to-discourage-people-encouraging-reposting) and [Better “Flag for migration” interface](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210545/better-flag-for-migration-interface)

Comment: I think thats a great idea! Could you add an abstract at the top of the question? Like: Request for a "Receive-Questions" Queue on minor SE Sites. (You will word it better than I do)

Comment: "What is a better server-side programming language, Java or PHP?" err... no, noone on SE would want that question, not Programmers, not SoftRecs, is essentially primary opinion based.

Comment: @Braiam, it's rather humorously obvious you stopped reading my question as soon as you got to that part.  Please read the subsequent paragraph, as I make the same point you do using almost the same words.

Comment: Repetition is necessary to engrave the words on the soul of the voters ;)

Comment: I think you forgot to mention [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)... we're getting so many questions asking for recommendations daily... It'd be nice to have an easier way to suggest migration rather than leaving a comment with a link asking OP to go over there and post a dupe. Maybe finally people will realize such a thing exists and it'll come out of beta..

Comment: Wait... this is a pull request, right?

Comment: I like this idea in principle, but it might force small sites to drink from the proverbial fire hose if we start sending questions with a *single* migration vote into this new queue. This could (maybe) be solved by 1) creating a threshold (3 votes, say) before putting a question in the queue and 2) automatically aging questions out of the queue fairly quickly.

Comment: @TJ SoftRecs has a very strict quality control, most SO questions asking for recommendation wouldn't fly there. Also, the site is in beta.

Comment: It would be very good if the SE could finally find a solution to deal with the misguided questions. For example like it has been suggested in this question: move these questions to the right place, instead of voting them dishonorably. The right word would be: nominating. Every question could start in lobby and nominated to site.

Answer (score 23):

The real problem with migrations is migrating questions that the destination site doesn't want. There are two main reasons another site might not want a question:

1. The question is of low quality.
2. The question doesn't belong there.

Something interesting to note about both of those: that's what the new Triage queue is supposed to help filter out. Most of the time, it's easy to spot low quality questions to obliterate them here before someone thinks of sending it along. The second one is a bit tougher. We on StackOverflow can't really make that call (unless we also happen to be active on the other site), but we can make a guess and then let someone from that site take a look at it. But the Triage queue will soon give all sites a fairly systematic way of filtering through new questions to make that call.

So, to throw an idea out on the table for discussion, what about rethinking our migration policy once the Triage queue is finalized and actually in use? Off-hand, I imagine giving triagers a way to migrate questions over to other sites (with enough agreeing votes), and this automatically throws it into Triage on the other site, irrespective of any other conditions.

Problems:

- Would that be too much additional work on triagers?
- Is that something super difficult to implement?
- Is the number of good questions that would actually successfully migrate over actually worth the implementation effort (and the effort of the originating site)?
- What about questions that get migrated to the wrong site, but do belong on another site? Would we allow multiple migrations?
- Others?

Comment: It would be nice to have some kind of statistic on the volume of questions that this approach would generate for other SE sites (although I'm not sure this is easy/possible)

Comment: @Luigi Is there a way to get statistics on successful migrations that didn't get closed/deleted on the other site? That wouldn't paint the whole picture, but it might be a good window to start looking through, even if it's only a couple of sites. I would imagine such a statistic would be easier to get on the *destination* site, actually. If someone knows how to query that, just a couple would be a good start. SuperUser, Server Fault, and Programmers seems like a good set to look at first.

Comment: @jpmc26: Moderators have access to the statistics you refer to, however I'm not entirely sure if anyone other than the staff can divulge them. I do know they have been discussed before, e.g. when discussing the viability of Programmers as a migration path.

Comment: @BoltClock given that they are available to all 10k users on *both* sites... SO to P.SE in the past is 25% rejected (and all are moderator done). P.SE to SO is 11% rejected (standard migration path). These stats are for the last 90 days. Note that this may not completely agree with the stats on SO and is a known issue.

Comment: @MichaelT Can you see raw numbers, or only percentages? If you're just reluctant to give them, that's fine, too.

Comment: [27 migrated from SO to Programmers. 225 migrated from Programmers to SO](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7rJQU.png "screen shot of 10K tools"). Worth keeping in mind, [Migration stats not consistent between sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202188/165773): "it's a bug that counts question closed as duplicates "rejected" on the destination site, but not on the source site. Not counting them as rejected would be correct behaviour..." => 25% rejection of SO migrations is likely 1/2-1/3 fake, I recall several migrations closed as dupes at Programmers

Comment: @jpmc26 the lack of information at the time was completely based on the tool I had to use to write a comment - iPad. It was awkward to write too much (or keep switching between screens to verify that I had the right numbers).

Answer (score 6):

I was stumped with this issue a few days ago.  I ended up leaving a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330597/how-do-i-turn-an-adobe-illustrator-image-trace-to-an-object-with-a-stroke-and-co#comment43124568_27330597) encouraging the OP to either edit the question to be suitable for S.O. or flag for a moderator migration (neither happened, but that's not relevant to this issue).

Now, in that case I was suggesting a migration to Graphic Design.  I might not spend as much time on Graphic Design as I do on Stack Overflow, but I have used it enough to get 1000 rep.  I am fairly confident the question would be valid on that site, and would be answered after a few clarifying comments.

In contrast, I don't use the Programmers or Super User exchanges, and don't have a clear idea what is considered on or off-topic there.

So, my suggestion:

**Allow users who have a minimum number of rep points on this site *and* the target site to recommend a migration directly to that site.**

- Don't make the reputation minimum huge,since most of us tend to concentrate on one site or another, but make it more than the 100 welcome points you get for joining a new site: 500 maybe?  (Remember that rep is harder to earn on smaller sites.)
- Require 2-3 votes suggesting the same migration in combination with the required close votes (i.e., don't migrate unless it would be closed on the origin site).
- Let anyone voting to close see the suggested migrations so they can add support if they are eligible to do so.

In the Close dialog, after selecting "This question belongs on a different site", the next screen could have the standard migration options plus a drop-down listing any sites that the user can personally suggest based on their network rep.

Comment: Similar feature request on Meta SE: [Require minimum reputation on the target site for migration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74053/require-minimum-reputation-on-the-target-site-for-migration) (note that it was declined; see the end of Jeff Atwood's answer for the reason why)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks for the link.  Certainly, the pool of users able to migrate under this scheme would be small, but still larger than the pool of moderators who currently must handle custom migrations (unlike the linked question, I wasn't suggesting restricting the "standard" migratory pathways).