# What happens to migrated questions / migration requests now that we have triage?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration, triage

Now that triage is working for some time and help-and-improvement is better than a first prototype, does that change how migration should be handled?

Imho, a migrated question, especially if it is user-migrated (or was that mod-migrated?), should always be fast-pathed into triage, to verify the migration actually made sense and kick it back immediately if it does not.

Actually, triage might even be used to test a question which is only proposed for migration (though that might lead to too tight coupling between sites), which would hopefully reduce the load on moderators and might even allow opening some more sites for vetted migration when they get that system too.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278723/1394393